# Display error message for 3 seconds and then fades out

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Based on what my PHP file returns i want to show a message on top of the Web page.

```
$msg = "Success"; // or fail
$redirecturl = "index.php?msg=".$msg;
header("Location: $redirecturl");
```

HTML code

```
<?php   $msg=isset($_GET['msg']) ? $_GET['msg'] : "";?>
<div id="display-success"><?php echo $msg; ?></div>
```

Now if i get the `Success` message i need to print a small box that appears (for 3 seconds, then fades out) that shows the message `success` in a **green** background. And if its  `failure` then i want to display a message in a **Red** background for 3 seconds and then fades out.

Comment: try it on page load $("#display-success").fadeIn(3000);

Comment: better add a type="fail" or "success" to know what color to show.

Comment: and set the css class based on the type then use fadeIn and fadeOut.

Answer (score 3):

```
//by using setTime0ut

setTimeout(function() {
   $('#display-success').fadeOut().text('')
}, 10000 );

//by using delay()

$('#display-success').fadeIn().delay(10000).fadeOut();
```

---

Example 
[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/8ed5m5jr/)

jquery

```
$(".showMsg").click(function () {
    $('#display-success').fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
});
```

html

```
<button class="showMsg">Click Me</button>
<div id="display-success">The error Message</div>
```

Comment: I have provided a demo example. checkout it out.